# Send different value to server with select tag - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I want to send a different value to the server than what the text representation of the value is for a select field. All of my attempts at this seem to fail. Here is what I'm currently working with.

```
<td><%= f.select :code, ["BOB"], { value: "STEVE" }, { class: "account-rep-code", "data-user-codes" => current_user.code_list } %></td>
```

On submit of this example, I want to send `"STEVE"` to the server not `"BOB"`. But `"BOB"` keeps sending anyway. How can I adjust this so that "STEVE" sends to the server as the `value` of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder#select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) is defined as:

```
select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Where the `choices` parameter is an array of arrays, and the first value in each of them corresponds to the option "inner html", and the second one, to the option value. So in your case you could add `[%w[BOB STEVE]]` and this would give you an option like:

```
<option value="STEVE">BOB</option>
```

So

```
<%= form.select :name, [%w[BOB STEVE]], ... %>
```

Comment: Thanks Man! Makes perfect sense.